# Facebook feed groups pagination and limit no works fine

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I test my feed in facebook for show posts with limit string

Actually i use this kind of url with graph of facebook :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/962582957103509/feed?limit=10000
```

As you can see i put limit for eample 10000 in my group i have more of 50000 posts , but never let me show the amount i want , always show me no more of 190 entries and the other posts if i want see , need use pagination in the bottom of feed

It´s possible show more or howewer my code it´s wrong ?

---

By other side i see it´s no possible works fine with pagination in facebook for groups , always when you go to previous link always send the first post of feed , this it´s a bug or what happend , because i don´t understand why no works this , all time fail and for paginate results it´s necessary show next and previous links

I need some help in this because i try fix this problem 3 days ago and i can´t get any solution for this problem or bug with feed of facebook

The best regards

Comment: There is a limit how big limit can be. Just use pagination

Comment: What pagination , with feed only can use next or previous and previous no works never and return the first post , regards